# Tint UIImageView only works if used inside delay block

Tags: ios, swift

When Trying to tint an imageView using the following method, I have to use a delay in order for the UI to update. Where am I going wrong?

```
class func tintImageView(imageView : UIImageView, withColor color:UIColor) {

    var coloredImage = imageView.image?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)
    imageView.image = coloredImage
    imageView.tintColor = color
}
```

Delay function:

```
func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}
```

Example use:

```
            delay(0.011, closure: { () -> () in
                tintImageView(button.imageView!, withColor: tintColor)
            })
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is tintImageView being run on a background thread?  If so, your delay works because it is updating a UI element on the main thread like they need to be.

Comment: I think that fixed it... Total oversight. Thanks!